# NetworkOnMainThreadException in Thread.run()

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to run application by example from some tutorial. And in this app I have

```
class LoadThread extends Thread {

  @Override 
  public void run() {
    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    ... 
  }
}
```

And then I invoke this in the Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        new LoadThread().run();
    }
    ...
}
```

But I get the exception

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   pointing to the following line:

```
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

But why?.. This line is situated in `LoadThread.run()` that isn't main thread, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a `Thread`, call `start()`, not `run()`.

Comment: Thank you! Right, it solved the problem. I only still wonder why I wound up with namely this exception  - NetworkOnMainThreadException... I thought this error occur only when you try to do durable operations on main thread.

Comment: @Ksenia: All you were doing was calling your `run()` method. `run()` does not magically go on a background thread. That requires calling `start()`. So, your `run()` method was running on the main application thread, and you cannot do network I/O there.

Comment: At last i got it! Thank you very much!